# Strange behavior with containers in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have the following scenario: I have a few divs embedded in eachother, the main div has position:absolute, and floats happily somewhere in the middle of the screen.

The issue is that this main div is supposedly invisible in the beginning. 
If I hover over a menu point, it appears. This main div also has submenus, which also make other things appear-disappear, depending where the mouse is.

The strange part: On everything else, this works perfectly, but for some reason on IE 11, whenever one of the submenus child ul-s gets the display: block from the mouse over event listener, the main div decides just to disappear.

The fun part is, that the main div still has display: block in it. If I manually remove it, and re-add it, it reappers! But I cannot make both the submenu, and the main div make appear.

Anyone has experience regarding this? I tried searching the web whole and wide, and I cannot see any answers.

Oh, one more additional detail, it usually works regardless, but sometimes don't, only if the user is zoomed in (zoom > 125%) it does this with 100% accuracy. I really hate IE.

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Use `mouseenter/leave` instead of `mouseover/mouseout` events.